# Syntax error in regexp when connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to get a connection to my MySQL server, but I'm getting errors and I don't understand why.

Here's the method I'm using:

```
public ListeID lireBdd() { //retourne une liste contenant tous les id de la bdd
    IdEnvoyes listebdd = new IdEnvoyes();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://dontconnecttomyserverpls/freecovid"; 
        String user = "root";
        String passwd = "root";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);

        //Création d'un objet Statement
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
        //L'objet ResultSet contient le résultat de la requête SQL
        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM freecovid.idMalades");
        //On récupère les MetaData
        ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();

        while(result.next()){
            for(int i = 0; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                listebdd.addId((Integer) result.getObject(i));
            }
        }

        result.close();
        state.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listebdd;
}
```

and I'm getting these errors

```
06-24 11:35:59.176 4360-4360/com.iutlan.freecovid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.iutlan.freecovid, PID: 4360
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.acceptsUrl(ConnectionUrl.java:317)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:185)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
    at com.iutlan.freecovid.ConnexionBdd.lireBdd(ConnexionBdd.java:22)
    at com.iutlan.freecovid.MainActivity.testbdd(MainActivity.java:69)
    at com.iutlan.freecovid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 4:
(?<scheme>[\w\+:%]+)\s*(?://(?<authority>[^/?#]*))?\s*(?:/(?!\s*/)(?<path>[^?#]*))?(?:\?(?!\s*\?)(?<query>[^#]*))?(?:\s*#(?<fragment>.*))?
    ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.<clinit>(ConnectionUrlParser.java:89)
        ... 20 more
```

06-24 11:40:59.588 4360-4360/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4360 SIG: 9

Do you have an idea of what could be my mistakes?

Comment: What is the relevance of the term regex in this question's title?

Comment: I do not know, i'm very new to programming and the Exception is "Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 4:" If you would like to see more of my code for context, i'll gladly show more

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the MySQL Connector/J driver is using a regular expression feature (named groups), that is supported by the regular expression implementation in Java, but not by the regular expression implementation of Android.

In other words, the MySQL Connector/J driver is not compatible with Android. You might be able to fix this by downgrading to an earlier version of MySQL Connector/J (eg 5.1.x instead of 8.0.x).

However, you shouldn't use JDBC drivers from Android at all. Connecting directly to a remote database server like MySQL from mobile devices usually performs badly and is not very secure. It would be better to introduce a (Java) webservice to mediate between your application and the database.

Comment: I have the feeling I have answered this question before, but I couldn't find it to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm now using mysql 5.1. It is working although i now have a connection problem : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server